# How to use Multiple JdbcOperations and Multiple JdbcTemplates in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have 2 different datasrouces from which I want to use in the same file and query each of them using JdbcOperations implementation. Is this possible?

```
@Repository
public class TestRepository {

    private JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("dataSource1")
    private DataSource dataSource1;

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("dataSource2")
    private DataSource dataSource2;


    @Bean
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate1")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1(@Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate2")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1(@Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Inject
    public TestRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
    this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations; //HOW DO I SPECIFY WHICH JDBCTEMPLATE SHOULD BE USED FOR INITIALIZING THIS JDBCOPERATIONS
    }
}
```

Above is my code, note that JdbcOperations is initialized in the constructor. But no way to specify **which** jdbcTemplate should the jdbcOperations use.

Answer (score 0):

The qualifier should actually be put at the parameter level:

```
public TestRepository(@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate2")JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
    this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
}
```

Uses the bean named `jdbcTemplate2`

Comment: I tried this and getting this error: Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: you mean your `Repository` is both a configuraton class and an actual class?! You should really separate that in two classes.